# Copy constructor difference for std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

If my understanding is correct, the following declarations should both call the copy constructor of `T` which takes type of `x` as a parameter.

```
T t = x;
T t(x);
```

But when I do the same for `std::unique_ptr<int>` I get an error with the first declaration, while the second compiles and does what is expected.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> x = new int();
std::unique_ptr<int> x (new int());
```

Is there a difference in the two syntax for calling the copy constructor?

Comment: [There are at least 7 different ways of initialization in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

Comment: @Quimby thanks for the reference. I will check the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor of `std::unique_ptr<>` is `explicit`, which means, you need to write it in the first case:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> x = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int());
// or
auto x = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int());
// or make_unique()
```

Comment: Got it! In general is there a way to define different constructors for the two cases? Separate from the assignment operator too.

Answer (score 2):

`std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr( pointer p )` is an explicit constructor, so that form of initialization is not allowed. Initializing with `=` always requires a converting-constructor for implicit conversions.